# Why is pygame.init() needed?

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently been studying Pygame, and have stumbled upon the need to use `pygame.init()` to initialize all imported modules. My question is: **why is it necessary specifically for Pygame?** None of the other libraries I've worked with so far (Pandas, Numpy, NLTK, Pyautogui etc.) have required this.

Comment: The dupe is pretty good but doesn't quite give the explicit answer you might be looking for, which is that `pygame.init()` is (according to the doc) slow enough that you might not want to have it happen automatically when you don't need it.  Most modules either don't have this problem or choose to disregard it.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now! So it exists so that all modules are initialized at once at the start of the runtime, preventing any slowness in the middle.